# Oracle SQL, combine columns to one with custom type

Tags: sql, oracle, select, dynamic, casting

i want create a custom type with the name people_map with 10 elements of type "anytype" and maybe other types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE mem_type2 IS VARRAY(10) of VARCHAR2(15);
```

The second thing i have is a table with less or equal then 10 columns with different types. Let call this table people_table:

```
CREATE TABLE newnames (n varchar2(20),m int)
INSERT INTO newnames VALUES ('Beryl',0);
INSERT INTO newnames VALUES ('Fred',1);
INSERT INTO newnames VALUES ('a',2);
INSERT INTO newnames VALUES ('b',3);
INSERT INTO newnames VALUES ('c',4);
```

The third Thing i have is a table in which the result shoud be written like this:

```
CREATE TABLE club (id int, Members mem_type2);
INSERT INTO club VALUES (0, mem_type2('Brenda','Richard'));  
INSERT INTO club VALUES (1, mem_type2('Gen','John','Steph','JJ'));
INSERT INTO club VALUES (3,null);
```

I want create with sql statements from each row of people_table with all columns, a new table/result with one column of type people_map.

But i have only this:

```
UPDATE club SET members = CAST(MULTISET(SELECT m FROM newnames where  m=0) as mem_type2) WHERE id <3;
```

this works fine, but only for one column and it write:

```
id  Members
...
3   .MEM_TYPE2('Beryl','Fred','a')
..
```

I want This:

```
id  Members
1   .MEM_TYPE2('0','Beryl')
2   .MEM_TYPE2('1','Fred')
3   .MEM_TYPE2('2','a')
...
```

I hope it is now better to understand

Comment: Take a deep breath.  Delete this question.  Then start writing a new question.  This time, include sample data and the results you want.  Find a clear question that is not *any idea*.  If you can set up a SQL Fiddle, that is great.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can ask questions and get answers about problems you're having with software you've written, but it is not a place where you can post vague specifications and hope to get detailed answers. People here are very talented but cannot read your mind. When you ask a question you should include the code you've written and the specific errors you're getting, or the results your program produces and an explanation of the results you expected. Without that there's really not much we can do to help you. Again, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: In addition to what Gordon has suggested, why are you trying to do this? What problem is it trying to solve? In general, coming up with a generic solution is just asking for a whole boat-load of pain. See: https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Answer (score 0):

I hope i wrote it now better in my question.

At the moment i have something first solution.

```
CREATE TABLE club (id int, Members mem_type2);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE mem_type2 IS VARRAY(10) of VARCHAR2(15);
create or replace Type mem_type2_list as table of mem_type2;
Insert into club (members) (SELECT * FROM TABLE(CAST(MULTISET(SELECT CAST(mem_type2(n,m) AS mem_type2) FROM newnames) AS mem_type2_list))t);
```